# "mv: cannot stat file" in for loop

Tags: linux, bash, file-management, rename

I wanted to rename a lot of files with a pattern so I tried this for loop:

```
$ for f in *; do mv \""$f"\" \""HouseMD-S06E${f#*Episode }"\"; done
```

But I got this error:

```
mv: cannot stat `"House MD Season 6 Episode 01 - Broken (Parts 1 & 2).avi"': No such file or directory
```

So what I did was echo the mv commands to a file like this:

```
$ for f in *; do echo mv \""$f"\" \""HouseMD-S06E${f#*Episode }"\">>mv.txt; done
```

And the run the file with `source`.

Any ideas why the first for didn't work and how can I fix it?

Comment: y dont you try the rename script? It should be built in already. check out [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/renaming-multiple-files-at-a-shell-prompt.html) guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for escaping double quotes again. If you use double quotes, this will make sure spaces in the filenames are no issue, even when the variable `$f` is expanded.

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" "HouseMD-S06E${f#*Episode}"; done
```

If you have these "double double quotes", let's assume you have the file `foo`, then the shell will try to run the command:

```
mv ""foo"" …
```

And obviously, `"foo"` does not exist – only `foo` – and this is why it fails.